# Casting a Matrix4 class to float*

Tags: opengl, c++

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "projMatrix"), 1, false, (float*)&projMatrix);
```

`projMatrix` is a an object of type Matrix4 where the first variable declared is a float array. Does `(float*)&projMatrix` therefore somehow retrieve this array? What does the casting appear to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only works, because you supply a pointer to the beginning of the matrix object, which by chance is the same as the beginning of the float array. I wouldn't personally rely on this behaviour, since it can make your code fail silently if you just change the order of two lines, add a new line in front of it or change the matrix library.

Comment: This is the code I've been supplied with, and it seems to work. I'm just not sure how.

Comment: @Edward addes explanation

Comment: @Edward - your Matrix4 class should have a public method or operator[] to retrieve the float array rather than relying on casts.

Answer (score 1):

What this does is get a pointer to the start of the Matrix object and then `reinterpret_cast` that to a pointer to floats using c-style casting shorthand `(float *)`.

It happens to work because the Matrix class happens to only contains the float cells or the cells are right at the beginning of the Matrix class.

**If any other member variables ever gets added to the beginning of the Matrix class or any virtual functions* this will stop working**

(*Due to the virtual table pointer that is put at the beginning of the struct/class in memory by some compilers, in full accordance with the C++ standard.)

What you want to do to improve maintainability is add implicit (or explicit) `operator float *()` cast operators that will return a pointer to the first float of the cell array:

```
struct Matrix4 {

  // cells[row][column]
  float cells[4][4];

  operator float *() {
    return &(cells[0][0]); // get pointer to first cell
  }

  // const version
  operator const float *() const {
    return cells[0]; // alternative way to write it
  }

};
```

(alternatively 4x vec4 can be used for the rows)

Then you can remove the `(float*)&` "magic" and just pass the matrix object directly

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, false, projMatrix);
```

If using C++11 or later you can add `explicit` to both operators to fix some implicit cast issues and ambiguities:

```
explicit operator float *() { ...
```

Comment: It's worth noting that GLM's `vec4` suffers from the exact same problem, but it is carefully crafted to work correctly on all implementations by GLM's developers. That way you can pass the hot potato and be assured it will work.

Comment: Theres a little issue with this `float *` implicit cast is that `if(my_matrix)` will compile as the compiler figures out it can convert a float * to a bool and happily do something that makes no sense.
A similar issue will happen if you accidentally compare a matrix with a float pointer, the compiler will convert the matrix to `float *` and you'll have fun finding the issue. You will need to add more operators to prevent this (by assuming the pointer points to 16 floats and comparing values) or force the cast to be **explicit**. There's no perfect solution.